# What's wrong with newChat.style.setAttribute("width", "100px"); in content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This works:

```
newChat.style.width = "100px";
```

But this one doesn't:

```
newChat.style.setAttribute("width", "100px");
```

Both are inside a function, in content.js (Google Extension content script).

With the second one I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function content.js:112
createChat content.js:112
(anonymous function) content.js:137
m.event.dispatch jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
r.handle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

style is a `CSSStyleDeclaration` object it doesnt have a setAttribute method.

You are wanting to either set the `style` attribute of the element using the [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) method of the element, or use use the [setProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration#Syntax) method of the `CSSStyleDeclaration` object to set a specific css property

```
newChat.setAttribute("style", "width:100px;");
//or
newChat.style.setProperty("width","100px");
```